# Perl one-liner prints everything except the last line

Tags: perl

I have a file. I want to print all the lines except the last one. How can we do this with a Perl one-liner?

This is not working:

```
cat file|perl -lane 'print if not eof()'
```

---

My bad, this is working. I didn't look at my output closely.

```
seq 1 6 | perl -lane 'print if not eof()'
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I think you mean "except" last line?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: The last line always comes unexpected to me as well, just like the last bottle of beer in the fridge :-(

Comment: If you want to do this in pure perl, I'd suggest you delay for one line and print the last when a new one comes in - on eof you dont print the one you have in buffer.

Comment: sorry, I didn't look my output closely. it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All I can say is...

## ***It works on my computer!***

(rimshot!)

So, exactly what are you getting? Is it an error message or does the program run? Does it print out any lines?

There is a difference between `eof()` and `eof` which might might be causing some of your concern (although both work on my system). According to [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html):

> An eof without an argument uses the last file read. Using eof() with empty parentheses is different. It refers to the pseudo file formed from the files listed on the command line and accessed via the <> operator. Since <> isn't explicitly opened, as a normal filehandle is, an eof() before <> has been used will cause @ARGV to be examined to determine if input is available. Similarly, an eof() after <> has returned end-of-file will assume you are processing another @ARGV list, and if you haven't set @ARGV , will read input from STDIN ; see I/O Operators in perlop

By the way, the `cat` isn't needed. This is the same, and it saves you from creating an extra process:

```
perl -ne 'print if not eof()' < file
```

And, you should be able to do this:

```
perl -ne 'print if not eof()' file
```

Answer (score 14):

If you need to do this on the command line, you can use the shell command `head`.  A negative number of lines will show all but the last N lines.

```
head --lines=-1 filename
```

This is a GNU extension and won't work with BSD head, for example the stock head which comes with OS X.

For Perl, your code is basically correct but there's no need to involve `cat`.  Otherwise you're reading the file twice.  You can pass the filename in directly.  Also `-l` effectively does nothing there, stripping the newline off the input and putting it back onto the output.  Finally, there's no need for `-a` as this wastefully splits each line into `@F` which is not used.

```
perl -ne 'print if not eof' filename
```

Comment: +1 for complete explanation and suggestion for using head and the suggestions of the various parameters that aren't needed.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have been reading this? [Famous Perl One-Liners Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-six/)

These both work for me with Perl 5.10:

```
cat myfile | perl -ne 'print if not eof'
cat myfile | perl -lane 'print if not eof'
```

What is wrong with the behavior which you are seeing?

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne 'print $last;$last=$_'
```

Comment: If we're golfing, `perl -pe'($x,$_)=($_,$x)'`

Comment: Or, more generally, to print all but the last `N` lines: `perl -pe 'push @s, $_; $_ = @s > N ? shift(@s) : q{}'`.

Comment: @ikegami: `perl -pe'eof&&last'`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'print unless eof'
```

But why does it have to be Perl? -

```
sed '$d'
```

Golfing versions:

```
perl -ne'print if!eof'
sed \$d
```

Comment: I like perl because of regular expression. I am used perl.

Comment: Well, so if you like golfing `perl -ne'print if!eof'` is even shorter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @sleeplessnerd:

> perl -ne 'BEGIN{$l=undef};print $l if (defined $l); $l=$_' file.txt